# How to query from multiple tenants of hibernate6 in a single request?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, quarkus, multi-tenant

I used TenantResolver from hibernate6 in Quarkus to perform multi tenant filtering, and of course, using CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver in springboot was the same issue. I found that TenantResolver only executes once in a request

### Background

CustomTenantResolver.java

```java
@PersistenceUnitExtension
@RequestScoped
public class CustomTenantResolver implements TenantResolver {

  @Override
  public String getDefaultTenantId() {
    return TenantUtil.NONE.toString();
  }

  @Override
  public String resolveTenantId() {
    var tenantId = TenantUtil.getTenantId().toString();
    System.out.println("resolve tenantId " + tenantId);
    return tenantId;
  }
}
```

TenantUtil

```java
public class TenantUtil {

  private static final ThreadLocal<Serializable> tl = new ThreadLocal<>();
  public static final Serializable ROOT = "-1";
  public static final Serializable NONE = "-999";

  public static void clear() {
    tl.remove();
  }

  public static Serializable getTenantId() {
    return tl.get();
  }

  public static void setTenantId(Serializable tenantId) {
    tl.set(tenantId);
  }
}
```

TenantFilter

```java
@Priority(0)
@Provider
public class TenantFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter, ContainerResponseFilter {
  @Override
  public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    String tenantId = requestContext.getUriInfo().getQueryParameters().getFirst("tenantId");
    TenantUtil.setTenantId(Objects.requireNonNullElse(tenantId, TenantUtil.NONE));
  }

  @Override
  public void filter(
      ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) {
    TenantUtil.clear();
  }
}
```

RoleResource

```java
@Path("/role")
public class RoleResource {

  @Inject RoleRepository roleRepository;

  @GET
  @Path("list")
  public List<SysRole> list() {
    return roleRepository.select().fetch();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("test")
  public void test() {
    TenantUtil.setTenantId("123");
    System.out.println(roleRepository.select().fetch());
    TenantUtil.setTenantId("456");
    System.out.println(roleRepository.select().fetch());
  }

}
```

### Expected

`curl http://127.0.0.1/role/list?tenantId=123`

```json
[{"id":"1", "tenantId": "123"}]
```

`curl http://127.0.0.1/role/list?tenantId=456`

```json
[{"id":"2", "tenantId": "456"}]
```

### Problem

`curl http://127.0.0.1/role/test`

```
[{"id":"1", "tenantId": "123"}]
[]
```

The `CustomTenantResolver.resolveTenantId` only executed once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tenant is determined upon EntityManager creation, and the EntityManager is generally bound to your transaction. Or by default to your request, but don't rely on that, [transactions are your friend](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#why-always-having-a-transaction-manager) and Hibernate ORM in Quarkus is read-only outside of transactions anyway.

So I think you'll have to use a different transaction for each tenant:

```java
public class RoleResource {

  @Inject RoleRepository roleRepository;

  @GET
  @Path("list")
  @Transactional // You really should use transactions
  public List<SysRole> list() {
    return roleRepository.select().fetch();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("test")
  public void test() {
    QuarkusTransaction.requiringNew().run(() -> {
        TenantUtil.setTenantId("123");
        System.out.println(roleRepository.select().fetch());
    });
    QuarkusTransaction.requiringNew().run(() -> {
        TenantUtil.setTenantId("456");
        System.out.println(roleRepository.select().fetch());
    });
  }

}
```

See [this documentation for how to work with transactions](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction), and in particular [this section about `QuarkusTransaction`](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#programmatic-approach). Alternatively [you can use the standard `UserTransaction`](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction#legacy-api-approach) but it's much less practical IMO.